# Rewrite URLs - Custom Post Type - Post Slug, Taxonamy Slug

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, slug, mod-rewrite, rewrite-tag

Am using a third-party plugin for listing schools.

Custom Post Type = `school`

Custom Post Taxonomy 1 = `school_type` (eg. values = `Primary`, `Intermediate`)

Custom Post Taxonomy 2 = `school_location` (eg. values = `Auckland`, `Otago`)

In my current setup, each school (individual posts) can be accessed like this:

```
http://example.com/school/snells-beach-primary
http://example.com/school/murrays-bay-intermediate
...etc
```

And URL of school types taxonomy would look like these:

```
http://example.com/school_type/primary
http://example.com/school_type/intermediate
...etc
```

URL of school locations taxonomy would look like these:

```
http://example.com/school_location/auckland
http://example.com/school_location/otago
...etc
```

What am trying to achieve is, after the `http://example.com/school/`, whatever there is in the slug should check for the individual post slug and route, if not found, then it should check either `school_type` or `school_location` taxonomies and pull the data.

So in the above examples, the new URLs would look like these:

```
-- individual posts
http://example.com/snells-beach-primary
http://example.com/murrays-bay-intermediate
...etc

-- school type taxonomy (as archives)
http://example.com/primary
http://example.com/intermediate
...etc

-- school location taxonomy (as archives)
http://example.com/auckland
http://example.com/otago
...etc
```

I installed the [Rewrite Rules Inspector](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) plugin to check the current rewriting to view the current rewrite rules. Based on that I added the following code as a new plugin:

```
add_action( 'init',  function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'school/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?school_location=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'school/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?school_type=$matches[1]', 'top' );
} );
```

The above will work for accessing these URLs now (for `school_type` taxonomy):

```
-- school location taxonomy (as archives)
http://example.com/auckland
http://example.com/otago
```

But both the individual school post URL and the school_location URLs won't work after this. Then I tried changing the third parameter in `add_rewrite_rule` in my code, to `bottom` for both lines. And then the individual school post URLs are working, but both the school_type and school_location URLs are not!

So how can I add the rewrite rules( for the URL: `http://example.com/XXXXX`) in the following order of precedence:

```
- XXXXX = individual school post
- XXXXX = school_post or school_location
```

---

**EDIT**

After some more research, I found that if there are multiple rewrite rules with same regex, only one will make it to the `rewrite_rules_array` (based on the `top` or `bottom` priority).

So I tried slightly tweaking the regex, so that all my rules will be included :

```
add_action( 'init',  function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'school/(.+?)[/]?$', 'index.php?school=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'school/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?school_location=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'school/([0-9a-z-]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?school_type=$matches[1]', 'top' );
} );
```

Again flushed and checked using the Rewrite Rules Inspector. Found that my 3 rules were present in rewrite_rules_array. But unfortunately, only the first rule is matched and then it will stop looking at the other rules. So if there's a school post, then it will be displayed, otherwise a 404 page. It's not checking the next rule!

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You are not going to be able to do this sort of thing with multiple "rewrite rules" (and these rules do conflict). A rewrite rule is processed and the request ends (essentially). There is no concept of a "return state on failure" so that the next rule can be processed.